# Saving data from inputs to file for later viewing in JS

Tags: javascript

I am just learning JS and I want to create a file for my own purposes only and to learn more about JS.

I am creating a self-esteem journal where the answers to questions will be saved daily and previous entries can be recalled later on.

I'm at the point where I need to save the answers provided to a file: can be TXT or a cookie, it doesn't matter, but it will just be on my local HDD.

Please help:

```js
function setDayQuestions() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getDay()
  var day = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  today = day[n] + " " + mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  document.getElementById('TodayFull').innerHTML = (today);
  switch (n) {
    case 0:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Sunday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "A positive thing I witnessed ...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "Today was interesting because...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "I felt proud when...";
      break;
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Monday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "Something I did well today was...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "Today I had fun when...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "I felt proud when...";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Tuesday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "Today I accomplished...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "I had a positive experience with...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "Something I did for someone...";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Wednesday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "I felt good about myself when...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "I was proud of someone else when...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "Today was interesting because...";
      break;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Thursday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "A positive thing I witnessed ...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "Today I accomplished...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "I felt proud when...";
      break;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Friday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "Something I did well was...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "I had a positive experience with...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "I was proud of someone else when...";
      break;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById('DayQs').innerHTML = "Saturday Questions";
      document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = "Today I had fun when...";
      document.getElementById('Q2').innerHTML = "Something I did for someone...";
      document.getElementById('Q3').innerHTML = "I felt good about myself when...";
      break;
    default:
      document.write("Blurnsday?");
      break;

  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function writeToCookie() {
      document.cookie = "TEST";
      var x = document.cookie;
      alert(x)
    }
  </script>
  <title>Self-Esteem Journal</title>
</head>

<body onload=setDayQuestions()>

  <h1 id="TodayFull">MON 01 01 01 01</h1>
  <h2 id="DayQs">DAY Qs</h2>

  <h3 id="Q1">q1</h3>
  <input id="a1">

  <h3 id="Q2">q2</h3>
  <input id="a2">

  <h3 id="Q3">q3</h3>
  <input id="a3">
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Results" onclick="writeToFile()">
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to save `TodayFull`, `DayQs`, `Q1-3`, and `A1-3` to a file. Thanks.

Comment: To write to a file, you'll need to use something like node js. You could write to local storage to save it to the browser instead, or you could save to a database.

Comment: To expand on @symlink's answer. JavaScript in the browser can not write to files (but to "browser local storage" - you need to look that up). If you need to write to a file you'll need to send a HTTP request (usually a POST or a PUT) to a HTTP server. So you'll need a HTTP server that receives a HTTP request from your JavaScript and puts the data therein into a file. That can be Apache calling a CGI script written in shell or IIE executing ASPX.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store cookie (or use localStorage) for local files.
You should use server for this.
If you really need to be client-only page, then you can offer file download via JavaScript.
[Check out this link for more info.](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)

This is code that you need:

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.txt", "This is the content of my file :)");
```